# Download files from huge list in Python

Tags: python, list, http, download

I have a list with 2M+ file links and would like to download them. My current approach is using urllib.urlretrieve, but it does it serially and really slow. 
How could I speed it up? Is it possible to do it asyncronously (and how)?

Comment: Nothing prevents you from dividing the list into N smaller lists and running the urllib based program on each list simultaneously...

Comment: Just write it directly to the file. Are you doing any console output? Remove this and should be faster

Comment: Check out the [`concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor) class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running Python 3.4+, you can use the stdlib [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) module to write asynchronous code. See [`aiohttp`](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.org/en/stable/) for an async web client. There are countless examples of making parallel requests using [`aiohttp`](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.org/en/stable/), so use those as a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have a large list of tasks (retrieve file and store somewhere) which are independent of each other and can be run in parallel.

I would suggest looking at something like Celery. http://www.celeryproject.org/ Read what it's about and see if you agree its a good fit for your problem domain.